# Beautifulsoup findAll returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using beautifulsoup, but findAll() returns an empty list. This is my code:

```
URL = "https://elcinema.com/en/index/work/country/eg?page=1"
r = requests.get(URL) 

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 
 
recordList = bsObj.findAll('a', attrs = {'class':"lazy-loaded "})

print(recordList)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which data do you need?

Comment: I've manually checked the HTML code and have not found any cases of `a` tags having `lazy-loaded` classes, so bs4 is doing the job correctly. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to find `img` tags with a `class` lazyloaded

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://elcinema.com/en/index/work/country/eg?page=1"
r = requests.get(URL) 

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html') 
 
recordList = bsObj.findAll('img',class_="lazy-loaded")
recordList =[i['data-src'] for i in recordList ]


print(recordList)
```

Output:

```
['https://media.elcinema.com/blank_photos/75x75.jpg', 'https://media.elcinema.com/uploads/_75x75_2fe90cb32f2759181f71eb2a9b29f0735f87ac88150a6a8fd3734300f8714369.jpg', 'https://media.elcinema.com/uploads/_75x75_3d90d1ee22c5f455bc4556073eab69cd218446d6134dc0f2694782ee39ccb5bf.jpg', 'https://media.elcinema.com/uploads/_75x75_81f30061ed82645e9ee688642275d76a23ee329344c5ac25c42f22afa35432ff.jpg', 'https://media.elcinema.com/blank_photos/75x75.jpg',.......]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, it looks like you need to find all `a` records who have `img` tag in it with a specific class `lazy-loaded` Follow the below code to get those:

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://elcinema.com/en/index/work/country/eg?page=1"
r = requests.get(URL)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
outputdata=[]
recordList = bsObj.findAll('a')
for record in recordList:
    if record.find("img",{"class":"lazy-loaded"}):
        outputdata.append(record)
print(len(outputdata))
print(outputdata)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)